# Dynamically read values from JSView

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have some values displayed in a table in a JSView and I would like to read the value of a particular line and display it in the same column of the table.

For example:

In  the first row

- Field1 has the value `"My App"`
- Field2 has the value `"Test"`

In Field3 I would like to have `This is my App Test`.

In the second row

- Field1 has value `"My App"`
- Field2 has value `"Test2"`

In Field3 I would like to have `This is my App Test2`.

What will be the best way to read the values dynamically and put it in Field3?

Here is my view definition:

```
sap.ui.jsview("views.TEST", {

    getControllerName: function() {
        return null;
    },

    createContent: function(oController) {
        var oLayout = new sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayout({
            width: "100%"
        });

        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

        oModel.loadData("My Data");


        var oControl;
        this.oSHTable = new sap.ui.table.Table("soTable1", {
            visibleRowCount: 10,
        });


        oControl = new sap.ui.commons.TextView().bindProperty("text", "Field1");
        this.oSHTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
            label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({
                text: "Col1"
            }),
            template: oControl,
            sortProperty: "Field1",
            filterProperty: "Field1",
            filterOperator: sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ,
            flexible: true
        }));

        oControl = new sap.ui.commons.TextView().bindProperty("text", "Field2");
        this.oSHTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
            label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({
                text: "Col2"
            }),
            template: oControl,
            sortProperty: "Field2",
            filterProperty: "Field2",
            filterOperator: sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ,
            flexible: true
        }));


        oControl = new sap.ui.commons.TextView().bindProperty("text", "Field3");
        this.oSHTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
            label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({
                text: "Col3"
            }),
            template: oControl,
            sortProperty: "Field3",
            filterProperty: "Field3",
            filterOperator: sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ,
            flexible: true
        }));

        this.oSHTable.setModel(oModel);
        this.oSHTable.bindRows("/");

        this.oSHTable.setTitle("List");
        oLayout.createRow(this.oSHTable);

        return oLayout;

    }
});
```

Field1 and Field2 are coming from OData services and it's working fine.

Comment: code please! show us what you have done!

Comment: Can you try the following when you initialize your TextView for Field3: `oControl = new sap.ui.commons.TextView(text: "This is {Field1} {Field2}");`. Also add the following in your index.html: `data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax="complex"`

Comment: Doesn't work... any other ideas ?

Answer (score -1):

You can easly generate the 3rd field content with the first two by setting `id` dynamically.

Have a looke to this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zowk9nbs/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I would like to read the values of field 1 and 2 and not just the counter.